# jQuery get div contents and send to php script via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get the contents of a div and send that to ajax.

Here is a sample code of ajax that sends data but **how can I put the html contents of a div in this post and send it to another php script via ajax?**

I need to send ALL the HTML in the "sortable" ui and not just the text.

```
<ul id="sortable">

<li class="ui-state-default">Hello, please send me to Ajax! :)</li>

</ul>


$("button").click(function()
  {
      $.post("get_sorted_content.php", // Example script
      {

       data: $("#sortable").html(); // My NEEDED content - Does not work!

     function(data)
       {

       alert("Data: " + data + ");
       });
 });
```

Again, This code may be missing some elements but regardless it doesn't work. It's just an example showing what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the AJAX method as an example here because I think it's a little clearer about what you want to do. Let's retrieve the **li** contents and sent it to your PHP script.

Don't bind to the `button` element, that is not very specific at all and will bind to any button on the page. Instead, give it an `id` and bind to that.

Your main problem is that you're getting the HTML of the **ul** with id `sortable`, not the specific `li` element you're after.

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Hello, please send me to Ajax! :)</li>
</ul>

<button id="clickme">Click me!</button>

// bind to the button with clickme ID
$("button#clickme").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_sorted_content.php',
        type: 'POST', // GET is default
        data: {
            yourData: $('#sortable li').html()
            // in PHP, use $_POST['yourData']
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Data returned from PHP: ' + msg);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            alert('AJAX request failed!' + msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Now in your PHP script, you can access that data with `$_POST['yourData']`:

```
<?php
// get_sorted_content.php
if(!empty($_POST['yourdata']))
    echo 'data received!';
else
    echo 'no data received!';
?>
```

**EDIT**: following having seen your statement: `I need to send ALL the HTML in the "sortable" ui and not just the text.`, if you need the **entire** `ul` contents, use what you had originally:

```
data: {
    yourData: $('ul#sortable').html();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `$.post` call needs to change as follows:

```
$.post('get_sorted_content.png', 
          { data: $("#sortable").html()},
          function(data){
              //data is whatever you send back from php script.
          }
      );
```

if `$("#sortable").html()` does not work, try to escape the HTML like:

```
escape($("#sortable").html());
```